# Laravel date validation based on two separate inputs; a date input and a time input

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-5.6

I would like to validate a form date in Laravel based on a datepicker input for the date and a separate time picker input for the time:

```
<input class="form-control datepicker" name="datepicker_date">
<input class="form-control timepicker" name="datepicker_time">
```

Processing all working fine and here's the Laravel validation rules:

```
'datepicker_date' => 'required|date|after:' . date('Y-m-d H:i', time()),
'datepicker_time' => 'required|date_format:H:i',
```

This is working as it's checking the date given is after the current time (and as no time is supplied the time being checked would be 00:00:00').

I need to take the timepicker field into account as part of the validation rule so if they have selected 15:00 the date that is validated is 2018/09/09 15:00:00. At the moment is it is 2018/09/09 00:00:00.

How can I inject the time that has been picked into the 'datepicker_date' input or consider the datepicker_time field as part of the datepicker_date validation rule?

---

Thanks for your help Mücahit Cücen. This is what I have now:

```
 $this->request->add([
        'datetime' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($this->request->get('datepicker_date') . ' ' . $this->request->get('datepicker_time')))
    ]);
```

and

```
 'datepicker_date' => 'required|date',
 'datepicker_time' => 'required|date_format:H:i',
 'datetime' => 'required|date|after:' . date('Y-m-d H:i', time()),
```

I'm getting the error 'The datetime field is required.' though. It is being added to the collection as I have dd()'d and can see it, but the validator is not picking it up? I tried using the request->merge function and got a function doesn't exist error?

---

UPDATE: ok it's quite hacky but I managed to get round this issue by adding the

```
   $this->request->add([
        'datetime' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($this->request->get('datepicker_date') . ' ' . $this->request->get('datepicker_time')))
    ]);
```

part in to the authorize() function, presumably because it gets called before the rules() function so the new request parameter gets added. Any better suggestions welcome :)

Answer (score 2):

You can try this.

Before your validation code:

```
$request->merge([
    'datepicker' => $request->get('datepicker_date').' '.$request->get('datepicker_time'),
]);
```

And you can validate it like this,

```
'datepicker' => 'required|date|after:' . date('Y-m-d H:i', time())
```

I did not try but this can solve your problem.

Edit: request->all output;

```
"datepicker_date" => "2018-09-14"
"datepicker_time" => "12:26"
"datepicker" => "2018-09-14 12:26"
```

Comment: Thanks for your help - I think it's pointing me in the right direction. Having trouble with the merge function though as it's not recognised. Will update my question with new details